# React Native - Make an absolute positioned element touchable over a text input

Tags: react-native

I'm building a Login form in react native with 2 textinputs, one for the mobile phone number and one for the password. The mobile phone input also has the possibility to select the country code with a dropdown, as shown in the following images:

[image: Image with closed dropdown]
[image: Image with open dropdown]

From the main screen component, I insert the two textinputs as custom components:

```
<CustomInput type="phone" style={/* ... */} ...props />
<CustomInput type="password" style={/* ... */} ...props />
```

Then, in the phone `CustomInput` I position the dropdown with `position: 'absolute'` and custom top/left positioning. I also used the `zIndex` property in order to display the dropdown above the actual TextInputs, and it works great. The dropdown is composed by a list of

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={/* do stuff */}>
    <Text>text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

While there are no problems on iOS, on Android the buttons that overlaps with the password textinput are not tapped, i.e. when I actually tap them, the underlying TextInput gains focus instead on triggering the TouchableOpacity `onPress` property. I tried different combinations of `zIndex` without success.

Is there any possible workaround for this issue, like forcing the tap priority of elements positioned one over the other?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?